# How to set multiple select values from string using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a span Id with some values that correspond to values in multiple select box items. I want to take the values from span Id and select the corresponding items in list.

```
<span id="test">
  1,4
</span>
<select id='multipleSelect' multiple='multiple'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

I can read the string into array but not sure how to use array to select items in multiple Select box

```
var test = $("#test").text();
var testArray = test.split(',');
```

I guess if the values are known then it is easy to do something like this

```
$('#multipleSelect').val(['1', '2']);
```

Here is JS fiddle to illustrate the idea so far
https://jsfiddle.net/deu8ftpb/1/

Comment: You were very close to solution `$('#multipleSelect').val($("#test").text().trim().split(','));` https://jsfiddle.net/8621wujp/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/suyesht/deu8ftpb/3/  Check this updated fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code. You just missing ***trim()*** that texts and put splitted array as val()

```
var test = $.trim($("#test").text());
var testArray = test.split(',');
$('#multipleSelect').val(testArray);
```

Comment: $.trim only removed the space around the first string. It works fine after using replace(/\s/g, "")

Comment: The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string. Refer https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right. You only forgot to set the val for the select.
Like so: `$('#multipleSelect').val(testArray);`

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit late.

You have to trim value in array.

In your case, I resolved using .map and trimming values

```
var test = $.trim($("#test").text());
var testArray = test.split(',');
var testArray = testArray.map(function(item){ return item.trim(); });
$('#multipleSelect').val(testArray);
```

I had a similar case but my "testArray" was an integer array (instead of strings like your testArray was). In my case I had to use .map for converting value from integer to strings.